# django-restframework booleanfield default=true

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a model field:

```
class User(models.Model):
    ...
    wish = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

and the serializer:

```
class WishSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    wish = serializers.BooleanField(default=True)
    class Meta(object):
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'user', 'wish')
```

Now I want to post a new wish and set "wish = True"
But the result is still False.

what can i do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are affected by a bug in version 2.3.8 of DRF that was fixed in recent versions. This bug basically resulted in ignoring the default value for BooleanFields

See the bug report:
https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/issues/1101

If you upgrade it should be fixed.